# Как шифровать строку во время компиляции? c#

Tags: c#

У меня есть строка которую должна быть в проекте зашифрованная, где то на гитхабе видел, что у человека строка шифровалась уже после компиляции проекта, но не смог найти его снова

Comment: MsBuild PostBuild targets

Comment: ну добавь строку в ресурсы, ее зашифруй. к примеру в бейз64 храни. только вот если все так секурно, то c# наверное будет даже с обфускатором отладчиком найти место где эта строка расшифровывается, и посмотреть как. если у тебя ключ будет храниться в коде, то вероятно это защита от дурака. дураку, от дурака хватит и base64 :)

Comment: @Yakov, это в любом случае защита от дурака, потому что если приложение само способно без внешних данных расшифровать, то достать будет можно.

Comment: Никогда не храните пароли в коде приложения.

Comment: Проблема в том, чтобы зашифровать строку, нужен ключ, ключ тоже надо зашифровать, потому что его хранить в открытом виде небезопасно, для этого нужен ключ, ключ тоже надо зашифровать, потому что его хранить в открытом виде небезопасно, для этого нужен ключ, ключ тоже надо зашифровать, потому что его хранить в открытом виде небезопасно, для этого нужен ключ, ключ тоже надо зашифровать, потому что его хранить в открытом виде небезопасно, для этого нужен ключ...